# How to temporarily modify sys.path in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

In one of my testing scripts in Python I use this pattern several times:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "somedir")
mod =  __import__(mymod)
sys.path.pop(0)
```

Is there a more concise way to temporarily modify the search path?

Comment: Note: `sys.path.pop(0)` works only if `mymod` doesn't prepend another path without removing it. And if that happened pop would remove the wrong path.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use a simple [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
import sys

class add_path():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.path.insert(0, self.path)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        try:
            sys.path.remove(self.path)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Then to import a module you can do:

```
with add_path('/path/to/dir'):
    mod = __import__('mymodule')
```

On exit from the body of the `with` statement `sys.path` will be restored to the original state. If you only use the module within that block you might also want to delete its reference from [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
del sys.modules['mymodule']
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.  Is it better to remove the path as you don't know the code within the context manager's context is not going to modify sys.path itself?

Comment: Yes, it may be better in such cases. Just use `sys.path.remove(self.path)` instead of `sys.path.pop(0)`.

Comment: to add to @dementedhedgehog 's suggestion: you might also want to catch a `ValueError` raised by `sys.path.remove` in case the code in the context has already removed the path itself

Answer (score 21):

Appending a value to `sys.path` only modifies it temporarily, i.e for that session only.

Permanent modifications are done by changing `PYTHONPATH` and the default installation directory.

So, if by temporary you meant for current session only then your approach is okay, but you can remove the `pop` part if `somedir` is not hiding any important modules that is expected to be found in in `PYTHONPATH` ,current directory or default installation directory.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: I cannot think of a different way, however as already mentioned, the variable sys.path will only keep its modified value within this Python session. Normally, there is no need to remove a path from sys.path, at least I cannot think of a good reason to do so.

A really permanent modification of sys.path would require that you modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable of your shell.

Comment: @JohannesP If "somedir" is hiding(masking) some module that is expected to be found in found in `PYTHONPATH`,etc then we can remove that entry to fix that.

Comment: I remove the directory after import to not slow down the search (there potentially can be hundreds of paths)

Comment: @planetp then it's perfectly okay.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative implementation of the contextmanager implementation from Eugene Yarmash (use `contextlib` and `pathlib.Path`-compatible):

```py
import os
import sys
import contextlib
from typing import Iterator, Union

@contextlib.contextmanager
def add_sys_path(path: Union[str, os.PathLike]) -> Iterator[None]:
    """Temporarily add the given path to `sys.path`."""
    path = os.fspath(path)
    try:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
        yield
    finally:
        sys.path.remove(path)


with add_sys_path('/path/to/dir'):
    mymodule = importlib.import_module('mymodule')
```

Comment: For someone in the future that got here but can't understand what `Union` and `Iterator` are doing: search phrases "annotation" and "type hint/check" may help.

Comment: `Union` is basically like 'one or the other', and since the function yields, it returns an iterator

Answer (score 3):

If you're testing uses `pytest`, they have a great [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html) that, among other traits, handles this exact case:

> The monkeypatch fixture helps you to safely set/delete an attribute,
> dictionary item or environment variable, or to modify sys.path for
> importing...
> All modifications will be undone after the requesting test function or
> fixture has finished. The raising parameter determines if a KeyError
> or AttributeError will be raised if the target of the set/deletion
> operation does not exist

In describing `syspath_prepend`:

> Use monkeypatch.syspath_prepend to modify sys.path which will also
> call pkg_resources.fixup_namespace_packages and
> importlib.invalidate_caches().

sample use:

```py
def test_myfunc(monkeypatch):
  with monkeypatch.context() as m:
    m.syspath_prepend('my/module/path')
    mod =  __import__(mymod)
  # Out here, the context manager expires and syspath is reset
```