# Import binary package from different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following directory structure:

```
root
  /src
    file1.py
    file2.py
  /libs
    __init__.py
    package.so
```

I wish to import `package.so` within `file1.py`.

I've tried the following import statements to no avail:

```
from .libs.package import func
from libs.package import func
from .libs import package
from libs import package
```

I want to avoid having to set `PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path`.

Is there a simple way to do this? I assume the issue is due to the package being a shared object and not just a Python file - I don't have access to the source code for it.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: You can. If `package.so` is in the same directory as `file1.py`, for example, `import package` works just fine. I just wish to have the binary package in a separate directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder tells me that there is no clean way to do it.

Comment: @AdamMitchell any updates on your progress?

Comment: [A nice approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211078/how-to-temporarily-modify-sys-path-in-python) to the modify-sys.path solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are intent on not using `sys.path.append` to import the file, I was able to do it using the following snippet in `file1.py`:

```
import imp
import os
file = os.sep+os.path.join(*os.path.realpath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-1]+['..','libs','package.so'])
package = imp.load_source('root.libs.package', file)
print package.a()
```

Which prints `<root.libs.package.a instance at 0x101845518>`. Note that my package.so file is just a python file that defines a dummy class `a` so that I could test importing it. From what I have read, I believe that replacing `imp.load_source` with `imp.load_dynamic` may be what you want.

Breaking it down:

`os.path.realpath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-1]` gets you the path to the directory the currently-running script is in, as a list of strings.

`+['..','libs','package.so']` concatenates a list containing the parent directory (`..`), the `libs` directory, and your filename to that list, so that os.path.join will build the full path to the `package.so` file.

`os.path.join(*[that list])` unpacks the list elements into arguments to `os.path.join`, and joins the strings with `os.sep`. I also add a leading `os.sep` since it is an absolute path.

`imp.load_source` returns a module with the name `root.libs.package` loaded from the file path.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) source was useful for writing this answer, and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) are the docs for the `imp` module, which you might also find useful.

Comment: As much as I appreciate this answer, this method defeats the point of my question. Maybe I should have explicitly stated that I didn't just want to avoid using `sys.path.append`, I wanted a nice clean one line solution. Alas, it seems that this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative import as described in python docs:-[here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)

Also it only works well for directories under package which will not ask for beyond import. If so will happen then this error will occur:-

`valueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

You can refer this question too for same:-
[value error for relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Answer (score 0):

In order to import a file from the directory above, you should use `..`

In your case, you need to import using one of the following lines:

```
from ..libs.package import func
from ..libs import package

from root.libs.package import func
from root.libs import package
```

Keep in mind that according to the python documentation, using a full path instead of `..` is preferred, thus `from root.libs` is a better choice.

Regarding not being able to traverse up: If your main script is `file1.py` you should start it from the directory containing `root` like so:

`python -m root.src.file1 args`

This way python will treat your root as a package.

Last but not least: As you're using Python 2, you'll need to put `__init__.py` in every directory, including `src` and `root`.

Comment: You've obviously not attempted any of your solutions with a `.so` file.